# Feature Request: StackOverflow favorite page with top pagination

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits

Suggest adding top pagination for favorite page like the following, please!

[image]

Comment: (very closely) related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49543/add-page-navigation-at-the-top-of-the-screen

Comment: @balpha should this be closed then?